# Visual Studio 2015 build drop location

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

Our company recently updated TFS to 2015 update 1. After that context menu item named `Drop folder` disappeared from completed builds. I found nothing about it and how to bring it back. When I click `Open` on completed build, VS opens web version of TFS where I forced to click through the menus and copy drop folder path manually. So I decided to write a simple extension that will add this item to the menu.
Some googling brought me to [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2011/04/08/tfs-2010-adding-a-menu-item-to-the-completed-builds-context-menu-in-the-build-explorer.aspx). But it seems that the example code is quite old and not working in VS2015:

```
IVsTeamFoundationBuild vsTfBuild = (IVsTeamFoundationBuild)GetService(typeof(IVsTeamFoundationBuild));
IBuildDetail[] builds = vsTfBuild.BuildExplorer.CompletedView.SelectedBuilds;
```

Property `SelectedBuilds` is always empty. I suppose that it relates to old window from VS2010. It returns items that are instance of [`IBuildDetail`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuilddetail.aspx) interface.
So I found this piece of code [here](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2015/MZ2015006.aspx):

```
var teamExplorer = (ITeamExplorer)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITeamExplorer));
var page = teamExplorer.CurrentPage;
var buildsPageExt = (IBuildsPageExt)page.GetExtensibilityService(typeof(IBuildsPageExt));
var build = buildsPageExt.SelectedBuilds[0];
```

Here `build` is the instance of [`IBuildModel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.controls.extensibility.ibuildmodel(v=vs.120).aspx) interface. It lacks `DropLocation` property.

Is there any way to found drop location of selected build? Or maybe latest build?

Comment: Which API version are you using?

Comment: How to check this? I use libraries from VS2015 folder. All dlls show 14.0.0.0 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after digging through TFS API, I ended up with this workaround.

```
    private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = (ITeamFoundationContextManager)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITeamFoundationContextManager));
        IBuildServer buildServer = context.CurrentContext.TeamProjectCollection.GetService<IBuildServer>();
        var teamExplorer = (ITeamExplorer)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITeamExplorer));
        var buildsPageExt = (IBuildsPageExt)teamExplorer.CurrentPage.GetExtensibilityService(typeof(IBuildsPageExt));
        var menuCommand = (MenuCommand)sender;

        if (menuCommand.CommandID.Guid == CommandSetCompleted)
        {
            foreach (var buildDetail in buildsPageExt.SelectedBuilds)
                Process.Start("explorer.exe", GetBuild(buildServer, buildDetail).DropLocation);
        }

        if (menuCommand.CommandID.Guid == CommandSetFavorite)
        {
            var definitions = buildsPageExt.SelectedFavoriteDefinitions.Concat(buildsPageExt.SelectedXamlDefinitions).ToArray();

            foreach (var build in GetLatestSuccessfulBuild(buildServer, definitions))
                Process.Start("explorer.exe", build.DropLocation);
        }
    }

    private IBuildDetail GetBuild(IBuildServer buildServer, IBuildModel buildModel)
    {
        Uri buildUri = new Uri(buildModel.GetType().GetProperty("UriToOpen").GetValue(buildModel).ToString());
        return buildServer.GetBuild(buildUri);
    }

    private IBuildDetail[] GetLatestSuccessfulBuild(IBuildServer buildServer, IDefinitionModel[] buildDefinitions)
    {
        var spec = buildServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec(buildDefinitions.Select(bd => bd.Uri));
        spec.MaxBuildsPerDefinition = 1;
        spec.QueryOrder = BuildQueryOrder.FinishTimeDescending;
        spec.Status = BuildStatus.Succeeded;

        var builds = buildServer.QueryBuilds(spec);

        return builds.Builds;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **IBuildDedetail.DropLocation** in [.NET client libraries for Visual Studio Team Services (and TFS)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet). Basic code for your reference:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;

namespace BuildAPI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string project = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(project));
            IBuildServer ibs = tpc.GetService<IBuildServer>();
            var builds = ibs.QueryBuilds("TeamProjectName");
            foreach (IBuildDetail ibd in builds)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ibd.DropLocation);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We have 635 build definitions. Many of them build regularly. I want drop location for one specific selected build. How do I know, which one to choose from `builds` collection?

Comment: @JohnPreston Then you can use GetBuild method to get specified build. See this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuildserver.getbuild(v=vs.120).aspx. And also, since you are using TFS2015, it support Rest API, you can also use this API to get these information. Link: https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/build/builds#Getbuilddetails

Comment: `GetBuild` works with build URI. `IBuildModel` doesn't contain this property. But private class BuildModel does. I used reflection to get it value. Shame on Microsoft for such poor API. Thank you for help.